# OLS and Fixed Effect showing same results

Tags: least-squares, fixed-effects-model

I am currently working on a tax paper and using a panel data of three Asian countries. after running OLS and Fixed Effect both shows the same results. is it possible to have same results? my function is tax= agriculture, GDP per capita, inflation, trade, aid, employment, urban population, corruption and government effectiveness beside this i also included two dummies in mly y model. Kindly guide me.

Comment: A fixed effects (fixed intercepts) model for panel data is algebraically equivalent to linear regression where the units are coded with binary dummy variables. You will see exactly the same coefficients and p-values.... Now, random effects are more interesting.

Comment: i cannot apply random model because the number of variables and countries are not equal. i have 3 countries and 9 variables.